# Build xpath based on quesrystring

Tags: xslt, sitecore

I am trying to make a rather simple 'search' in xslt. 
I have a base xpath expression. The user can then select some values in 3 select boxes and submit. This return 3 parameters i can get via querystring.
I then need to add some expressions to my xpath based on the selections in the selectboxes.

I am using XSLT 1.0 in Sitecore.

Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given much of a clue as to the type of parameters, but if say `param1` is an element name `param2` is an id value then an xpath such as

```
//*[name()=$param1][@id=$param2]
```

will select element(s) with name given by the first parameter that have an id attribute with value given by the second.

If you want the last predicate to only check the id value if the parameter is non empty then

```
[$param2='' or @id=$param2]
```

Comment: Sorry - the parameters are @id's. But how would you make the above statement dynamic'? Meaning if parem2 is empty, it should not check for this in the xpath?